# Solving a cubic limit without using rationalization

Tags: calculus, limits

Starting from
$$
\lim_{{x \to \infty}} \left( x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x \right)^{1/3} - x=
$$

$$
=\lim_{{x \to \infty}} \left( x \left(1 + \frac{5}{x} + \frac{8}{x^2}\right)^{1/3} - x \right)
$$

Is there a way to continue the limit without using rationalization?

Comment: Hint: as $y\to0$, $(1+y)^\alpha-1\sim\alpha y$. Apply this to $\alpha=1/3$ and $y=\frac5x+\frac8{x^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand $(1+ \frac{5}{x} + \frac{8}{x^2})^ \frac{1}{3}$ using the binomial expansion for any index. Using that we get $x(\frac{1}{3}(\frac{5}{x} + \frac{8}{x^2}) + ....)$. We are in search for the coefficient of $\frac{1}{x}$ as everything else when multiplied with $x$ tends to 0. Thus we get the limit as $\frac{5}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

A very clever way is by factorization, using that

$$A^3-B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2) \iff A-B=\frac{A^3-B^3}{A^2+AB+B^2}$$

we have

$$ \left( x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x \right)^{1/3} - x =\frac{\left( x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x \right) - x^3}{\left( x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x \right)^{2/3}+x\left( x^3 + 5x^2 + 8x \right)^{1/3}+x^2}=$$

$$=\frac{5+\frac 8 x}{\left( 1 + \frac 5 x + \frac 8{x^2} \right)^{2/3}+\left( 1 + \frac 5 x + \frac 8{x^2} \right)^{1/3}+1}\to \frac 5 3$$